# How to create pivot table that references data from multiple sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

Is it possible to create a pivot table that has its reference data in another sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Pivot table, you can see the following dialog:

[image]

- So yes, you can place your pivot table in a sheet that is distinct from the sheet that has the reference data.
- You cannot place it in a different spreadsheet, but you can copy it into a different spreadsheet.
- [image: List item]

Comment: I ment a different spreadsheet. If I copy the tab to another spreadsheet does it remain connected to the source data?

Comment: Unfortunately it won't - only the formatting of the table will be copied, not the data. What you can do is create in the other spreadsheet a sheet with the same name like the one to which the pivot table was originally linked, and then import the data from this sheet with `=IMPORTRANGE`. This will make sure that the data will be synched between the two spreadsheets and the pivot table updated accordingly.

Comment: I was trying to avoid importing the whole range. I need to create 1 file per person, it's arround 80 files with the same data source. I ended up doing that but I was expecting I didn't have to repeat the raw database for each file. Thanks anyway

Comment: I am sorry that I could not give you a more satisfying answer, but unfortunately this is the way Google sheets is designed.

Comment: Thanks anyway! There will always be a time where we hit the limit wall